# Apex Callout - Use Named Credential Password Placeholder in setEndpoint

Tags: apex, callout, namedcredentials, accesstoken

I've created an Apex class to call a custom rest api endpoint for a Snowflake database.
The call is pretty basic in that you just include the token and a query in the endpoint Url.
I would like to use a Named Credential to store call the Url and store the token in the Password field.

Below is the Http request I have configured and attached is a screenshot of my Named Credential.

If I define the token as a String variable in my Apex class and then add it to the Endpoint this works (see 1st commented out line).

However if I try to replace the variable with the Password Placeholder I receive the error `Illegal character in opaque part at index 24: callout:Snowflake?token={!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Password)}`.

I have triple checked the password in my Named Credential matches the the token variable in my Apex Class.  Also the token only contains alpha, numeric and dashes.

```
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setTimeout(timeout * 1000);
            //req.setEndpoint('callout:Snowflake' + '?token=' + token);
            req.setEndpoint('callout:Snowflake' + '?token=' + '{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Password)}');
        HttpResponse response = new Http().send(req);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about `EncodingUtil.urlEncode` instead?

Comment: I wanted to stick with the Named Credential so I could manage this outside of the class.

Comment: That does not solve my issue, but answers my question!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I missed this, but @identigral highlighted this article which confirmed Merge Fields are NOT supported in the Endpoint.